# How to store GPS tracking data in PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql, gps

I am currently developing GPS tracking program to track trips road, i have a mobile app in each car that sends GPS lat and longs each 
period of time to store the trip road, i have lots of trips, each user on the system can use the GPS tracking software, and i do not know the number of users,
I do not know how i can store the GPS lat and long in database, i want to 
use Postgres, i have two choices , i do not know if these choices is stupid or not, any way, 
First one: is to store each trip road in a new table the name of the table is like the primary key of the trip. 
Second one add all lat and longs on one table and add trip id column as a primary key to retrieve the road.

Comment: thank you Mr.Milen A. Radev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Anton, for sure saving all in a single table is convenient.
you need to install postgis even if it's not necessary for storing lan long you will find it very usefull after to manage geometry, projecting them and more over.
So the pk for id of trip and a postgis poliyline in WKT format for trip path.
I did alredy several applications like this and postgres postgis together are the best of breed.

Luca

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to store all data in a single table. Let database engine do its optimization and caching job.